# How to make a full width render on ReferenceManyField?

Tags: react-admin

I have a `react-admin` show page configured with some `ReferenceManyField` components like this one:

```js
<ReferenceManyField
  reference="children"
  target="userId"
  label="Enfants"
>
  <Datagrid
    rowClick="edit"
  >
    <TextField
      source="lastName"
      label="Nom"
    />
    <TextField
      source="firstName"
      label="Prénom"
    />
    <DateField
      source="birthday"
      label="Date de naissance"
      showTime={false}
    />
    <TextField
      source="phoneNumber"
      label="Tél."
    />
  </Datagrid>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

It works, but the rendered tab are content sized:

[image: Reference array table render]

My question is quite simple: How to make it full width?

I tried the `fullWidth` option on `ReferenceManyField` without any effect.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a sample on CodeSandbox. I am using `ReferenceManyField` with the `fullWidth` option, and it expands properly for me.

Comment: @Cornul11 I'll clear some planning time to do that.

Comment: @Cornul11 `fullWidth` should really only work correctly with `*Input` components as per the official docs at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html. I am trying to find a similar solution for `ArrayInputField` and it does work if I add `fullWidth`, but there are warnings in the console about unrecognized prop.

Comment: Sorry, typo -- should've been `ArrayField`.